# How to include custom php file inside wordpress plugin directory?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am developing custom payment gateway which i need to process tranasaction_id and other payment details through custom php file which will be in the plugin directory. Also i am getting 4 times ajax request loading for the response what i am getting how to avoid it.

```
// plugin class file payment-gateway.php

//response.status ="approved";
//response.transaction_id ="324234";
var dataString = JSON.stringify(response);                       
                jQuery.ajax({
                     type : "POST",
                     dataType : "json",
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     url: '<?php echo plugins_url().'/custom-woocommerce-gateway/includes/custom_php_file.php'; ?>',
                    data: {myData:dataString},
                     success: function(response) {


                        }
                        }); 

/*custom-woocommerce-gateway/includes/custom_php_file.php */
<?php 
//define the wc functions

print_r($_REQUEST);
process the payment details like woocommerce

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this function is located on a file of your plugin, you should try to use instead [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/):

```
 url: '<?php echo plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/custom_php_file.php'; ?>',
```

> But with the provided code and details, nobody can solve your problem of ajax multiple request loading.
>
> In StackOverFlow, you can't ask multiple questions at once. You need to split and ask a question at the time, *"including the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"*. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).